# Magento: Is there a way to set all configurable products to "Not Visible Individually"

Tags: sql, database, magento, product

I want to set all the children of configuarable products to "Not Visible Individually" and the checkbox under Websites activated also for children of configuarable products.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

If you have access to mysql directly you can do this:

The relation from configurable childs and parents are store in `catalog_product_super_link`
so all products in this table are simple that are childs of a config.

visbility is stored as an integer and the representation of "Not Visible Individually" is "1"

Now we can use this query, however if you have a local or staging system try it their first!

```
UPDATE catalog_product_entity_int AS pei
JOIN 
    catalog_product_super_link AS sl ON pei.entity_id = sl.product_id
JOIN
    eav_attribute AS e ON e.attribute_code = 'visibility'
        AND pei.attribute_id = e.attribute_id 
SET 
    pei.value = 1
```

For the website checkbox use this insert select statement and replace **{the website id}** with your id

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO 
    catalog_product_website (product_id, website_id) 
SELECT product_id, {the website id} AS website_id FROM catalog_product_super_link;
```

Comment: Thank you, does this also set the Checkbox activated under websites?

Comment: Would you be so kind to insert the code for the website activation?

Comment: added the snipped, just replace {the website id} with your desired one

Comment: Do you mean the srore_id or the website_id?  My site return the number 1 as website_id

Comment: So if the number 1 is correct, the following: {1} AS website_id...... would be correct?

Comment: products can only be associated with websites. if you don't have multiple websites this step would not be needed. website_id = 1 is the default website so you have maybe another. check the "core_website "table if you are unsure if you run the query remove { and } before :)

Comment: When I run the above code, the following error message appears: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INSERT IGNORE INTO catalog_product_website (product_id, website_id) SELECT' at line 11

Comment: can you add the full query pls, because its running on my local system

Comment: I put my used query above

Comment: it should like this in the end you need to remove the {}:

INSERT IGNORE INTO 
    catalog_product_website (product_id, website_id) 
SELECT product_id, 1 AS website_id FROM catalog_product_super_link;

Answer (score 2):

If you don't have MySQL access, I believe this would also work:

```
$sites=Mage::app()->getWebsites(true);
foreach($sites as $site){
    $site_list[]=$site->getWebsiteId();
}

$products=Mage::getResourceModel("catalog/product_collection")->addAttributeToFilter("type_id","configurable");

foreach ($products as $product){
    $child_products = $product->getTypeInstance()->getAssociatedProducts();

    $child_product_ids=array();

    foreach($child_products as $child_product){
        array_push($child_product_ids,$child_product->getId());
    }

    Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_action')->updateAttributes(
        $child_product_ids,
        array(
            'visibility' => "1",
            'website_ids' => $site_list
        ),
        Mage::app()->getStore()->getId()
    );

}
```

Comment: Thank you, I am not an expert, but is teh activation of the website checkbox in your code?

Comment: I've updated the snippet so it should now do that as well. Although as Fantus said, make sure you test it out first in a development environment, if you have one :)

Comment: Thanks. How do I run this script?

Comment: I'd say either as a data upgrade script or a shell script. If you don't have command-line access to whatever environment you'll ultimately be running this on, I'd say a data upgrade script is your best bet. Do you have any custom modules already? (i.e. - something you could tack the upgrade script on to)

Comment: I would have to check. An SQL script although would be easier for me

Comment: No worries. I'm glad Fantus was here to help. I generally prefer a SQL solution when available, but I freely confess to being not as familiar with Magento's DB structure, at least in regards to EAV. Good luck!